# innerHTML to Attribute value Plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is my html

```
<table><thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Green</th>
        <th>Orange</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>First Stage A</td>
        <td>First Stage B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second Stage A</td>
        <td>Second Stage B</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Expected output

```
<table><thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Green</th>
        <th>Orange</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Green">First Stage A</td>
        <td data-label="Orange">First Stage B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-label="Green">Second Stage A</td>
        <td data-label="Orange">Second Stage B</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Here is the script

```
    var _th = document.querySelectorAll("table th")[0];
    var _th_value = _th.innerHTML;
    var _td = document.querySelectorAll("table td")[0];
    _td.setAttribute("basevalue", _th_value);
```

How could this to be done through plain JavaScript loop. I tried to figure this out for several hours by my existing JavaScript knowledge. But I couldn’t. Could someone please take a look and give me a hint? Advance thanks.

Comment: Please add relevant JS code also..

Comment: Also, `data="Green"` is not valid [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute. you need to provide a name to it like `data-color="Green"` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:** You can first create a mapped array that contains the color values you can collect from the `table thead th` selector. You need to first convert a HTMLCollection to an array using ES6 [Array.prototype.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and then perform the mapping using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const colors = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('thead th')).map(th => th.innerText);
```

p/s: The reason why [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) is used is so that we don't include any HTML tags, even though in your example `innerHTML` works just as fine. This is just a personal preference.

**Step 2:** Then, you simply iterate through all the `table tbody tr` elements. In each iteration you then iterate through all the `td` elements you can find, and with their index, use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) to assign the corresponding color by index:

```
table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(tr => {
  tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((td, i) => {
    td.dataset.color = colors[i];
  });
});
```

---

See proof-of-concept below, where the cells are colored based on the `data-color` attribute for ease of visualisation (you can also inspect the DOM to see the correct HTML5 `data-` attributes are added):

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

// Collect colors into an array
const colors = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('thead th')).map(th => th.innerText);

// Iterate through all `<tr>` elements in `<tbody>
table.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(tr => {

  // Iterate through all `<td>` in a particular row
  tr.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((td, i) => {
  
    // Assign color to HTML5 data- attribute
    td.dataset.color = colors[i];
  });
});
```

```css
tbody td[data-color="Green"] {
  background-color: green;
}

tbody td[data-color="Orange"] {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Green</th>
      <th>Orange</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First Stage A</td>
      <td>First Stage B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second Stage A</td>
      <td>Second Stage B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution is elegant. I really appreciate your precious time. Your solution saved my googling hours. But sir, if the document has more than one table, it doesn’t work. Could you please help with that?

Comment: @Icado If that’s the case you need to iterate through all table elements on the page and then run the same code for every table element you come across.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

for (let table of tables) {
    var thead = table.children[0];
    var tbody = table.children[1];

    var index = 0;
    for (let th of thead.children[0].cells) {
        var color = th.innerHTML;

        for (let tr of tbody.children) {
            tr.children[index].setAttribute('data-label', color);
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

I had to handle the index outside the for loop because the `children` elements aren't simple arrays but `HTMLCollections`, and have different way to iterate over them.

**edit:** Added loop to iterate over all the tables in the page

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir. But it doesn’t handle more than one table in the same document. Could you please help me with the loop? If loop, the script can handle all the tables in the same page. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the solution in order to loop over all the tables

Comment: Thank you sir. Now, loop is handling all the tables in the page.